# Web Service file transfer, how to add retries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a bit of code that uses a Task to transfer a file over a web service. However if the network drops or a timeout occurs it results in an incomplete file. I'm really trying to make this service as reliable as possible, but I'm not really sure where to even really start to add code that will trap when a chunk was not sent, and then attempt to resend it multiple times but also not send the next chunk until that is done. And maybe if it cannot resend that chunk over X times, fail completely and log an event.

Can anyone suggest anything?

```
Action<Guid, string> action = (smGuid, pubAttFullPath) =>
        {
            try
            {
                //Set filename from object
                string FileName;
                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pubAttFullPath.ToString());

                //Declare Web Service
                TransferFile.TransferFileSoapClient ws_TransferFile = new TransferFile.TransferFileSoapClient();

                //
                bool transfercompleted = false;
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(
                     pubAttFullPath.ToString(),
                     FileMode.Open,
                     FileAccess.Read,
                     FileShare.Read))
                {
                    //Declare Buffers and Counts
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[49152];
                    long fileSize = fs.Length;
                    long totalReadCount = 0;
                    int readCount;
                    float percentageComplete = 0;

                    //Loop and copy file until it changes to not exactly the same byte count as the buffer
                    //which means the file is about to complete.
                    while ((readCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        if (!transfercompleted)
                        {

                            totalReadCount += readCount;
                            byte[] bytesToTransfer;

                            if (readCount == buffer.Length)
                            {
                                //Copy bytes until buffer is different
                                bytesToTransfer = buffer;
                                ws_TransferFile.WriteBinaryFile("ABCD", bytesToTransfer, FileName);
                                percentageComplete = (totalReadCount / (float)fileSize * 100);
                                percentageComplete = (float)Math.Round(percentageComplete, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
                                //Update progress to DB

                                InsertProgress.InsertProgressSoapClient ws_InsertProgress = new InsertProgress.InsertProgressSoapClient();
                                if (percentageComplete == 10.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 10.0);
                                }
                                if (percentageComplete == 20.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 20.0);
                                }
                                if (percentageComplete == 30.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 30.0);
                                }
                                if (percentageComplete == 40.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 40.0);
                                }
                                if (percentageComplete == 50.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 50.0);
                                }
                                if (percentageComplete == 60.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 60.0);
                                }
                                if (percentageComplete == 70.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 70.0);
                                }
                                if (percentageComplete == 80.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 80.0);
                                }
                                if (percentageComplete == 90.00)
                                {
                                    ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 90.0);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Only a part is requred to upload,
                                // copy that part.
                                List<byte> b = new List<byte>(buffer);
                                bytesToTransfer = b.GetRange(0, readCount).ToArray();
                                ws_TransferFile.WriteBinaryFile("ABCD", bytesToTransfer, FileName);
                                percentageComplete = 100;

                                //Insert Progress as complete
                                InsertProgress.InsertProgressSoapClient ws_InsertProgress = new InsertProgress.InsertProgressSoapClient();
                                ws_InsertProgress.InsertProgressService(smGuid.ToString(), 100);
                                transfercompleted = true;
                                fs.Close();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.Message.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web service is bad idea for file transfer. I used it few times, but amount of additional data transfered is making size of transfered data 1,5-2 times bigger then sending file using simple handler. Handler will allow you to the same without issues. It causes al lot of problem with proper progress handling and resume. You realy should reconsider using httphandler. If you like to use webservice, here is good example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you decide to use *IHttpHandler* see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

And then you can use following piece of code to proper handle retry/resume:

```
                using (Stream stream = new FileStream(
                 pubAttFullPath.ToString(),
                 FileMode.Open,
                 FileAccess.Read,
                 FileShare.Read))
                {
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                    context.Response.Buffer = false;

                    if (context.Request.Headers["Range"] != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
                        string[] range = context.Request.Headers["Range"].Split(new[] { '=', '-' });
                        startBytes = Convert.ToInt32(range[1]);
                    }

                    int dataToRead = size - startBytes;

                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, Encoding.UTF8));

                    if (startBytes > 0)
                    {
                        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format(" bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startBytes, size - 1, size));
                        stream.Seek(startBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    }

                    while (dataToRead > 0)
                    {
                        // Verify that the client is connected.
                        if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                        {
                            // Read the data in buffer.
                            int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            // Write the data to the current output stream.
                            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                            // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                            context.Response.Flush();
                            dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                            dataToRead = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: OK that sounds great thanks so much for your reply! I noticed using the web service it was much slower than i thought it would be. Question though, if I were to write this as a IHTTPHandler, what would the server side code look like for your client code example? The link to the IHTTPHandler info is pretty generic.

Comment: My sample is part of handler I'm using with proer headers handling to support download resume. But you need to rememebr to properly call this handler. Also client needs to support resuiming properly so you will need on client side put correct headers to let server know how many data is already downloaded.

Comment: Marcin - I implemented a IHttpHandler setup in my code and im trying to implement some type of progress reporting, can you suggest the best way to do that? I put my code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471127/ihttphandler-file-transfer-progress